# Показ картинки на ограниченное кол-во времени

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Есть button и две картинки. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на button первая картинка (img1) появлялась на 5 секунд и потом исчезала, а вторая (img2) просто появлялась, без исчезновения.

```
<button id="btn"></button>
<p class="img1"><img src="img1.jpg" align="center"></p>
<p class="img2"><img src="img2.jpg" align="center"></p>
```

Comment: Я не знаю как решить эту задачу, поэтому и обратился с вопросом. Поделитесь ссылкой, пожалуйста, если нашли решение.

Comment: по нажатию на кнопку выполнить 3 действия: а) показать картинку-1; б) показать картинку-2; в) запустить таймер на 5 сек, который, сработав, спрячет картинку-1. Что из этих трёх действий у вас вызывает сложность?

Comment: Все действия у меня вызывают сложность.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
var Btn = function() {
    var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
    var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');

    img1.style.display = 'block';
    img2.style.display = 'block';

    setTimeout(function() {
        img1.style.display = 'none';
    }, 5000);
};
</script>

<button onclick="Btn();"></button>
<p id="img1" style="display: none;" ><img src="img1.jpg" align="center"></p>
<p id="img2" style="display: none;" ><img src="img2.jpg" align="center"></p>
```